# What is the city at the end of "Twice upon a time"?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of *Twice upon a Time*, we saw

> the new Doctor (Jodie Whittaker) falling

over what appears to be an aerial shot of a small city.  Is it a real city on earth, and if so, what city is it?

[image: City from end of Twice upon a Time]

(Screenshot cropped to remove spoilers)

Here's the uncropped video (Spoilers):

Comment: Well, this shot was followed by the text "To be continued", so I'm afraid you'll just have to wait. Are you even sure it's Earth?

Comment: @MrLister: yes, I realise we'll have to wait until next season to get an in-show answer, and that it may not be real or even on earth. But if it *is* a real city, I’m hoping someone might recognise it already from the image…

Comment: Do you have an uncropped screen shot for those of us who already know whats going on?

Comment: Based on the rebooted Doctor's history, this city is quite possibly somewhere in the UK, modern day. Try using Google Earth in night mode (I think it has it), maybe you'll find a match

Comment: @doomista, yeah. I *think* it is london (with south at the top of the image) but I'm not sure. If there is more city we can't see, I'll probably say london. If empty land got cropped, its back to square one.

Comment: The scene is on Youtube: https://youtu.be/yJqsPBWbtjk?t=4m44s (uncropped)

Comment: IIRC it's empty land that got cropped. London was my first guess, but based on maps and imagery, I don't think that's the case (https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/78000/78674/london_lights_2012087_lrg.jpg) it's something much smaller. Interesting is that ultra light spot (big square or lot of interconnected squares). Also, this city does not have a road ring around it. London has it

Comment: Put the uncropped image.. We can hide it under spoiler tag..

Comment: I'm tempted to close this under our [future works policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5187/31394) (see also [this recent clarification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11594/31394)), as the answer will presumably become clear at the start of the next episode, but is probably unknown at this point (maybe even to the showrunners, if they just put a random nightscape in the background!)

Comment: I've found an article from 22. November which has photos of Whittaker filming new season of DW. Based on the clothes, I think these photos were from the first episode of the upcoming season and were taken in a rural area, which means there is a high chance that this was not a random nightscape. I can't google location where the pictures were taken though...

Comment: @Randal'Thor: the clarification describes the policy as closing questions that are “unanswerable now but will be trivially answerable from future works”. This question may become trivially answerable from future work (or may not), but at least if the answer is positive, then it's answerable now — if it's a real town or city, then someone could recognise it and justify that clearly.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not London - there's no river to be seen. The closest town I can see that might match the view is Guildford - but it's hard using Google Maps which has daytime satellite photos.

Comment: @PLL Yeah, that uncertainty is why I haven't just gone ahead and closed it. It *might* be unanswerable now, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @HorusKol Guildford is a nice guess but I don't think the streets match the picture. Also I'm pretty sure we would be able to see Aldershot in the video as well if it was it

Comment: @doomista - it's a bit of a stretch, but needs a rotation... I can't seem to find anything else that comes close, though.

Answer (score 4):

**It's *probably* [Sheffield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffield) UK**.

The first episode of Season 11 is set in Sheffield, which is also the place where the Doctor falls. Since she is already outside the Tardis and falling when we see the city, she probably could not have traveled (to, somehow, fall elsewhere). So the aerial shot is probably Sheffield.

Here's a picture (from google earth) of Sheffield by day, it does not look exactly like the night image, but all other nearby cities look almost nothing like the night image.

[image]